# After crash I can't access certain sections nor login to site

Tags: 7, views

I'm working on localhost. After saving a view the loading icon kept going for about 15 minutes. I changed over to other admin sections and they were fine, but after coming back to the original view the loading icon was still there. My clever answer was to log out and log back in to see if this fixed it. Oh terrible mistake, now I can't log back in, the page stays loading for a long time until finally returning a blank page. Being logged out I can still view the site's sections EXCEPT the view that crashed, that page just hangs.

I'm on a tight schedule so reinstalling would be my last option. Anyone has experienced this, how can I fix it from 'outside'? I'd appreciate any help, I'm growing desperate.

Thank you.

EDIT [SOLVED]:

Not much of a solution but I ended up restoring the DB with a backup file (luckily I had backed it up early today!) and the site works fine again.  I couldn't post this as an answer because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: you should put the solution as answer to your own question. Because, by not doing so the questions remains in unsolved questions' queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fix was to re-install the database from a backup I did.  Not exactly a solution to the problem but it worked :)